# Jenkins quits at midnight

Tags: jenkins, cmd

I am running Jenkins from cmd, not as a service, because I need to do GUI testing. It works fine when I start it up and I can do everything I want. But I schedule a task around 4am. and when I come back Jenkins didn't last till 4am. From the console, it seems to just quit at 12am.

First I thought it's computer environment problem. But it still happens after I change my computer to never sleep, and I put the hard drive to never sleep as well. I locked my computer around 7pm. But it seems to continue running until 12am.

Any idea on what is happening?

[image: Jenkins cmd output]

Comment: If this happened only once, I'd just see if it happens again...

Comment: If there's log output at 12:24 AM, then it's not quitting *at* midnight. Are there any scheduled tasks running? Anything mentioned in the Windows system log?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Jenkins logs. They're somewhere either in the directory where `jenkins.jar` was or in a subdirectoy, look for `jenkins*out*` and `jenkins*err*` files with right time stamp. I can't check exact location and names right now, sorry.

Seems you were running jenkins from `C:\`, congrats for cluttering your C drive root ;). To help clean it up, copy `jenkins.war` to `C:\jenkins\` or something and run it again to see what all it creates under there, so you know what to clean up.

Also, running it from C drive root might have somehow interfered with some Windows maintenance task or something, which caused it to abort.

Comment: I moved jenkins.war to C:\jenkins\. Ran it in the cmd. Output is very similar to what I attached before. There is no log in C:\jenkins\. I looked into C:\Users\user\.jenkins (This is where jenkin home is), I still cannot find a log file there. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, other than searching file system for those two patterns in my answer, not really. Btw, did having `jenkins.war` at root actually clutter your root folder, or did it extract all extra files under that `C:\Users\user\.jenkins`? Also, has the issue of Jenkins quitting happened again?